# is raising exceptions on assignment bad practise in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

Consider the following example where i would have to assign many variables to function calls that might return None. If they do return None an exception has to be raised.

```
some_variable = some_function_call()

if not some_variable:
    raise AnException(...)
```

Doing this over and over becomes tedious and harder to read in the end.
Is there some other way i should look at this to avoid all these `if not x: raise Exc`?

Would it be bad practise to instead write something like this? if so, why?

```
def raise_exception(exc):
    raise exc

some_variable = some_function_call() or raise_exception(AnException())
```

Comment: You could use `assert  ( some_variable := f() ), "my error message"`

Comment: Unless optimizations are enabled.

Comment: Yeah, I would not use `assert` for business logic

Comment: Does it have to be raise that early? Probably using the `None`later on would raise a `TypeError` or `AttributeError` anyway.

Comment: If you own `some_function_call`, you might consider having that function itself raise the exception on an error rather than returning `None`.  It depends a lot on what the function is actually doing, of course, but if a `None` result is likely to produce an error in the caller it's better IMO to raise immediately so that the caller doesn't need to check for `None` and raise its own error as you're having to do here.

Comment: @Samwise that is a good point but in this case i unfortunately do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing inherently wrong with your approach. Maybe an assignment expression is more readable:

```
if not (some_variable := some_function_call()):
    raise AnException(...)
```

Comment: something like this is what i was looking for. it is like you say more clear than what i wrote. thank you for this.